# What is the difference between RNAV-Terminal usage waypoints vs RNAV-STAR waypoints?

Tags: sid-star, jeppesen, rnav, waypoint, enroute

What is the difference between [MM604 (or) MM615] vs [RADAB (or) DAMAD] in the STAR attached below
[image: VOMM-STAR-DAMAD RNAV Departure]

When seen using Enroute Chart
The description for RADAB or DAMAD is:
[image: Enroute-RNAV-Terminal usage]

The description for MM604 or MM615 is:
[image: Enroute-RNAV-STAR usage]

What does does this 2 RNAV waypoint have a difference and how it is well interpreted in Airbus A320 FMGS F-PLN page in MCDU ?.

Comment: What "difference" are you seeing that you're asking about? I'm not seeing anything different between the two screenshots of the details beyond what's already obvious by considering the waypoint names (i.e. pronounceable vs MM###). What difference are you drawing attention to with the screenshots?

Comment: @RalphJ There is regulation on how enroute waypoints should be named (2 vowels and 5 alphabets). Similarly is there any naming convention followed to name star waypoint ? I am sure the difference must be more than just place of waypoint( enroute vs STAR/SID). kindly provide regulation document if you have it for SID/STAR Waypoint naming. Thanks